# convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence of $p$-th moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory

is there a simple way to prove that $X_n \rightarrow_{L^p} X$ implies that $\mathrm{E}(X^p_n) \rightarrow \mathrm{E}(X^p)$? the proof for $p=1$ is easy. but what about the case $p>1$? I would appreciate any comments. many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $0<a<b$ then, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that
$$
|a^p-b^p|=p\,c^{p-1}\,|a-b|\implies |a^p-b^p|\le p\,b^{p-1}\,|a-b|\le p\,(a^{p-1}+b^{p-1})\,|a-b|.
$$
Then
$$
|E(X_n^p)-E(X^p)|\le p\,E((X_n^{p-1}+X^{p-1})|X_n-X|).
$$
Now use Hölder's inequality an the boundedness of $E(X_n^p)$ to deduce that $E(X_n^p)\to E(X^p)$.

Comment: thanks for your help! great idea, I just don't see how the boundedness of E(X_n^p) kicks in (the conjugate Hölder-norm is the essential supremum, right?). so I would have to establish that the essential supremum of X_n^(p-1) is finite - but I don't know how to do that? any further hints? many thanks!

Comment: Let $q=p/(p-1)$ be the conjugate exponent of $p$. The $L^q$ norm of $X_n^{p-1}$ (which appears when you use Hölder's inequality) is precisely the $L^p$ norm of $X_n$, and this is bounded.

Comment: of course - silly me that I did not see it! many thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!